# Fixed Off-Canvas not scrolling

Tags: android, jquery, scroll, navigation, sass

I have been running into some problems that I do not understand.
I'm building a site with an off-canvas drop down menu, that refuses to scroll. I have added `overflow-y: scroll` and have been using pretty much the same thing on a few other sites, where it works like a charm. But as soon as I open this site with my Android, I cannot scroll the menu, if it overflows. I'm facing the problem with mobile firefox, chrome and opera, all the newest versions.

[live demo](http://bekreatief.github.io/demo/off-canvas/)

Full Code can be seen here: https://github.com/bekreatief/bekreatief.github.io/tree/master/demo/off-canvas

Menu markup:

```
<section class="main_menu">
    <nav id="menu">
        <a href="#" class="toggle_link"><i class="fa fa-close fa-lg"></i></a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item-has-children">
                <a href="#">Parent</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">subitem</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">subitem</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item-has-children">
                <a href="#">Parent</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">subitem</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">subitem</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">subitem</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Menu Sass

```
// Main Nav
.main_menu{
    background: $mainnav_bg;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    border-top: $border;
    border-bottom: $border;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block;
    background: $mainnav_bg;
    max-width: $max-width;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: $mainnav_a_color;
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 105;

    a{
        color: $mainnav_a_color;

        &:hover{
            color: $mainnav_a_hover;
        }
    }

    .toggle_link{
        display: none;
    }

    > ul {
        text-align: center;
    }

    li{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 20px 7px;
        transition: .3s all linear;

        > a{
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
        }

        &:hover{
            transition: .3s all linear;

            > a{
                color: $mainnav_a_hover;
            }
        }
    }

    // Drop Down
    .menu-item-has-children{
        margin-left: 0;
        position: relative;

        > a{
            &:before{
                content:"+ ";
            }        
        }

        > ul{
            padding-top: 0px;
            display: none;
            max-height: 100%;
            overflow-y: auto;

            @media screen and (min-width: $mainnav_collapse+1){
                background: $mainnav_bg;
                position: absolute;
                top: 100%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translateX(-50%);
                width: auto;
                border-top: $border;
                border-left: $border;
                border-right: $border;

                &:before{
                    content: "";
                    width: 10px;
                    height: 10px;
                    background: $mainnav_bg;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: -6px;
                    left: 50%;
                    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
                    border-left: $border;
                    border-top: $border;
                }
            }

            li{
                display: block;
                padding: 10px 0px;

                @media screen and (min-width: $mainnav_collapse+1){
                    padding: 10px 30px;
                    border-bottom: $border;
                }
            }
        }

        &:hover,
        &:focus{
            cursor: pointer;

            > ul{
                display: block;
            }
        }
    }
    .open{
        > ul{
            display: block;
        }            
    }

    // Responsive Version (Off-Canvas)
    @media screen and (max-width: $mainnav_collapse){
        padding: 35px 0px 0px;
        width: 320px;
        height: 80vh;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        right: -320px;
        transform: translate(10px, 10px);
        transition: .3s all ease;
        z-index: 108;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(black, .5);
        overflow-y: scroll !important;

        &.active{
            transform: translate(-340px, 20px);
            transition: .3s all ease;
        }

        .toggle_link{
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            right: 5px;

            &:after{
                content: "";
            }
        }

        > ul{
            text-align: $mainnav_responsive_text_align;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            max-height: 100%;
            overflow-y: scroll !important;
        }

        li{
            display: block;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            border-top: 1px solid lighten($mainnav_bg, 5%);

            &:first-of-type{
                border-top: $noborder;
            }

            &:hover{
                transition: .3s all linear;
                background: rgba($mainnav_a_hover_bg, .4);
            }
        }

        // Sub Items
        .menu-item-has-children{
            margin-left: 0;

            > ul{
                padding-top: 15px;
                display: none;

                li{
                    padding: 10px 0px;

                    &:first-of-type{
                        border-top: 1px solid lighten($mainnav_bg, 5%);
                    }
                }
            }

            &:hover,
            &:focus{
                cursor: pointer;

                > ul{
                    display: block;
                }
            }
        }
        .open{
            > ul{
                display: block;
            }            
        }
    }
}

// Toggle
.toggle_link{
    @media screen and (min-width: $mainnav_collapse){
        display: none;
    }
}
```

And js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Responsive Menu
    $(".toggle_link").click(function () {
        $("#menu").toggleClass("active");
    });

    $(".menu-item-has-children a").attr("aria-haspopup", "true");
    $(".menu-item-has-children a").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was caused by skrollr, which I intended on using on another part of the page. But since I am still developing, I removed skrollr and it is now working as intended.